# How do I use the great circle distance calculation in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can i control the latitude and the longitude of the Team and the Customer with reasonable error margin from the Job Table?

if the two values are close to eachother i will return it "true", if not "false"

Job Table (like this) :

```
JobID CustomerID TeamID
  2     13        1
  3     13        2
```

Team Table :

```
TeamID Latitude Longitude
 1      41.019   28.965
 2      42.019   27.165
```

Customer Table

```
 ID  Latitude Longitude
13  13.557   13.667
```

Comment: What does it mean to be "close to eachother"?, you need to be more specific

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667647/find-the-nearest-location-in-ms-sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DictanceKM(@lat1 FLOAT, @lat2 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT, @lon2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371
END
```

Answer (score 1):

i assume you mean:  how can i write a select statement to return true if two latitudes and longitudes are within x miles of each other... or something like that?

look up 'great_circle_distance'

write a query that links the customer to the team.

perform the great circle distance calculation on the two lats and longs.

compare this to you desired distance.

use decode or some similar construct to turn that into a 'True' or 'False' value.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has a geography datatype and a method to calculate the distance between two.  Covert your Lat, Long pairs to geography.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.stdistance.aspx 
Then you could use a function to return a true or false.