# Find stores within 10 miles of postcode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a list of stores with their post codes. What I need to do is when a user types in a postcode on the webpage it search the db and then finds the closest 10 to that postcode.

example of data i have:

```
ID  = 1
Store =Halfords 
Address 1 =Unit 6b
Address 2 = Braidfute Retail Park   
Address 3   = Lanark    
Address 4 =South Lanarkshire
Postal Code = ML11 9AE
Lat = 55.6711692810059
Long = -3.77314400672913
```

I am able to convert the postcode into longitude and latitude, what query do i need to run to find stores within 10miles in ym table of this cord

Comment: Do you have a data source that knows the location of postcodes?

Comment: Postal codes by themselves won't be of much use unless you have corresponding Geo coordinates. Do you have those?

Comment: All I  have is a database table with a store name and next to it a postcode and lat and long

Comment: I would recommend looking at this SO post to solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907873/distance-between-two-points-using-geography-datatype-in-sqlserver-2008

Comment: Postcode to lat/long is available for free from ordanance survey; http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html

Comment: sorry i need further help understanding how to use that function as im not good with stored procdures etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need the lat/lon of each postcode and store those in a table along with a geospatial representation (GEOGRAPHY, or GEOMETRY datatype). When a post code is entered by the user, you can the look up that post code in your db to find it's location.

You'll also need to store a GEOGRAPHY/GEOMETRY representation of each of the stores lat/lons you currently have.

Based on that, you can use all of SQL Server's geospatial functionality to perform geospatial searches.

I've made available on [GitHub](https://github.com/AdaTheDev/Ordnance-Survey-Code-Point-Data-Importer) a .NET app that will import the free Ordnance Survey postcode dataset (all post codes in GB) into SQL Server, converting all the Eastings/Northings provided by it, into lat/lon and then creating a geography column. I have a full blog post on that [here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/gb-post-code-geographic-data-load-to.html). The end result would be used like this:

```
DECLARE @home GEOGRAPHY
SELECT @home = GeoLocation 
FROM dbo.PostCodeData 
WHERE OutwardCode = 'AB12' AND InwardCode = '3CD' -- Postcode entered by user

-- find all stores within 10 miles of the entered postcode
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Stores
WHERE GeoLocation.STDistance(@home) <= (10 * 1609) -- 1609 = approx metres in 1 mile
```

Hopefully, this will be a good starting point.

Comment: sorry i still dont understand, i have the longitude and latitude of the entered post code, what query should i run against my table to find the items within 10miles?

Comment: You need to convert those lat/lon coordinates into an new column on your "store" table with a GEOGRAPHY datatype. Then you need a new table to hold the coordinates of every GB postcode (see my linked blog post). Once you have those, you can then run the query like I gave at the end of my answer. You need to read up on geospatial support in SQL Server first, get an understanding of that. Some good links here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551894/whats-the-best-way-to-store-co-ordinates-longitude-latitude-from-google-maps

Comment: Fantastic answer this will save me a lot of time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start with [Geospatial functionality in SQL Server](http://www.rightpoint.com/community/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2010/03/29/a-brief-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-geospatial.aspx).

Comment: Link is now dead.
It has ceased to be. It is no more... :(