# geodesic distance between visitors and closest store

Tags: python, google-bigquery, geodesic-sphere

I have a big .csv dataset containing 10e7 points with coordinates (latitude, longitude) representing locations of visitors. I have another dataset containing 10e3 points with coordinates representing locations of stores.

I want to associate to each visitor the closest store, using some kind of geodesic formula.

I want something really fast and efficient, which I can run on python (pandas for instance) or Google BigQuery.

Can someone give me a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to Felipe answer:

You can use SQL UDF vs JS UDF
JS UDF have some [Limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#limits) that SQL UDF do not

So equivalent SQL UDF you can use with the rest of Felipe's code is

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION distance(lat1 FLOAT64, lon1 FLOAT64, lat2 FLOAT64, lon2 FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64 AS ((
WITH constants AS (
  SELECT 0.017453292519943295 AS p
) 
SELECT 12742 * ASIN(SQRT(
  0.5 - COS((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + 
  COS(lat1 * p) * COS(lat2 * p) * 
  (1 - COS((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2))
FROM constants
));
```

I tried to preserve layout of respective JS UDF as much as possible so you can see how it is created

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick solution that finds the closest NOAA weather station for 21,221 cities in DBpedia (v2014).

```
#standardSQL

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION distance(lat1 FLOAT64, lon1 FLOAT64, lat2 FLOAT64, lon2 FLOAT64)
RETURNS FLOAT64
LANGUAGE js AS """

  var p = 0.017453292519943295;    // Math.PI / 180
  var c = Math.cos;
  var a = 0.5 - c((lat2 - lat1) * p)/2 + 
          c(lat1 * p) * c(lat2 * p) * 
          (1 - c((lon2 - lon1) * p))/2;

  return 12742 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a)); // 2 * R; R = 6371 km

""";

SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT city, country_label, distance, name weather_station, country, 
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY city ORDER BY distance DESC) rank
  FROM (
    SELECT city, a.country_label, distance(a.lat,a.lon,b.lat,b.lon) distance, b.name, b.country
    FROM (
      SELECT rdf_schema_label city, country_label, country,
        CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(point, r'(-?\d*\.\d*)') as FLOAT64) lat, 
        CAST(REGEXP_EXTRACT(point, r' (-?\d*\.\d*)') as FLOAT64) lon 
      FROM `fh-bigquery.dbpedia2014temp.City`
      WHERE point!='NULL'
    ) a
    JOIN (
      SELECT name, country, usaf, wban, lat, lon
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.stations`
      WHERE lat != 0.0 AND lon !=0.0
    ) b
    ON CAST(a.lat as INT64)=CAST(b.lat as INT64)
    AND CAST(a.lon as INT64)=CAST(b.lon as INT64)
  )
)
WHERE rank=1
```

Caveats:

- It uses the distance formula from https://stackoverflow.com/a/22476600/132438
- Optimizes by restricting JOINs by only searching for stations in the same INT(lat),INT(lon) than the city. It's possible to improve this, but I'll leave that for another question.

[image]