# SQL Server calculate distances between 2 sets of columns of latitude / longitude

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geolocation, geography

I'm trying to calculate the closest weather station to a given zip code.  I have data with the lat/lon for the weather station and the zip codes.  I also have a way to calculate distance for a 2 points ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude)).  What I'm looking for is a way to create a column that has the distances for multiple instances.

```
StationNum  lat     lon     Zip     lat      lon   distance
123         34.66   98.32   12345   33.78   91.91   ???
456         33.03   96.8    23456   35.23   92.23   ???
789         32.29   96.85   34567   33.09   92.68   ???
```

Is there a way to do that or do I need to write out the math by hand?

Comment: If you convert that to the `GEOGRAPHY` CLR type, there are some built in distance functions which I believe can take into account things like curavture of the earth. If you just need euclidian distance, I believe it can do that as well. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/stdistance-geography-data-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the GEOGRAPHY type

You had duplicate field names so I renamed them to Lat1/Lon1 and Lat2/Lon2.  If this is a join, add the alias a.lat/a.lon  b.lat/b.lon.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([StationNum] varchar(50),[lat1] float,[lon1] float,[Zip] varchar(50),[lat2] float,[lon2] float)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (123,34.66,98.32,12345,33.78,91.91)
,(456,33.03,96.8,23456,35.23,92.23)
,(789,32.29,96.85,34567,33.09,92.68)

Select * 
      ,InMeters = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat1], [Lon1], 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat2], [Lon2], 4326))
      ,InMiles  = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat1], [Lon1], 4326).STDistance(GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat2], [Lon2], 4326)) / 1609.344
 from @YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

> **Edit - For your consideration**

Consider adding a Geography field to your source table(s). This will eliminate the redundant `GEOGRAPHY::Point()` function calls

```
Update YourTable Set GeoPoint = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Lat], [Lon], 4326)
```

So then the calculation for distance would simply be

```
  ,InMeters  = A.GeoPoint.STDistance(B.GeoPoint) 
  ,InMiles   = A.GeoPoint.STDistance(B.GeoPoint) / 1609.344
```