# Calculating speed based on two coordinates SQL

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, math

I have table like this:

| lat | lon | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 51.04425273 | 6.26225570 | 2022-04-01 11:29:15.103 |
| 51.04424076 | 6.26200474 | 2022-04-01 11:29:09.106 |
| 51.04424345 | 6.26200506 | 2022-04-01 11:29:05.304 |
| 51.04427988 | 6.26203456 | 2022-04-01 11:29:03.231 |

I need to calculate speed (in km/h) between each two consecutive points (lat, lon). It would be ideal to also have differences in time and distance in separate columns. The first value should be empty, expected result:

| lat | lon | time | diff_time | distance | speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51.04425273 | 6.26225570 | 2022-04-01 11:29:15.103 |  |  |  |
| 51.04424076 | 6.26200474 | 2022-04-01 11:29:09.106 | ... | ... | ... |
| 51.04424345 | 6.26200506 | 2022-04-01 11:29:05.304 | ... | ... | ... |
| 51.04427988 | 6.26203456 | 2022-04-01 11:29:03.231 | ... | ... | ... |

I have already looked at some hints (e.g. [SQL Server calculate distances between 2 sets of columns of latitude / longitude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46204513/sql-server-calculate-distances-between-2-sets-of-columns-of-latitude-longitude)), but none of them fit my table form.

I was thinking about something like a loop, in Jupyter Python I did it like this:

```
df_sample['speed']=0.0

# determine how many rows are in the dataframe

nrrows=df_sample['lat'].count()
i=1
while i < nrrows:

    # determine the time passed between measured positions
    timedist=df_sample['time'][i-1]-df_sample['time'][i]

    # put timedifferenc into seconds
    timed=timedist.total_seconds()


    # determine the distance passed between measured positions with distance function
    dist=distance((df_sample['lat'][i-1],df_sample['lon'][i-1]),(df_sample['lat'][i],df_sample['longitude'][i])).km

    # if there two datapoints with the same time, put speed from the last calculation
    if timed==0.0:
        df_sample['speed'][i]=df_sample['speed'][i-1]
    else:
        # calculated speed in km/h
        df_sample['speed'][i]=(dist/timed)*3600.0

    # first data gets the speed from first to second datapoint
    if i==1:
        df_sample['speed'][i-1]=(dist/timed)*3600.0
    i=i+1
```

Now, I need to move this logic to MS SQL and I can't cope with such data manipulation in this environment. Is someone able to help?

Comment: In T-SQL, you could use a set-based query ordered by time, with a `LAG` windowing function to get values from the previous row.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same idea as @dan-guzman in the comment. Here's the implementation:

```sql
with cte as (
    select * from (values 
        (51.04425273, 6.26225570, '2022-04-01 11:29:15.103'),
        (51.04424076, 6.26200474, '2022-04-01 11:29:09.106'),
        (51.04424345, 6.26200506, '2022-04-01 11:29:05.304'),
        (51.04427988, 6.26203456, '2022-04-01 11:29:03.231')
    ) as x(lat, lon, ts)
), i1 as (
    select *,
        point = geography::Point(lat, lon, 4326)
    from cte
), i2 as (
    select *,
        ts_prev = lag(ts, 1) over (order by ts),
        point_prev = lag(point, 1) over (order by ts)
    from i1
), i3 as (
    select delta_m = point_prev.STDistance(point) , 
        delta_t = datediff(second, ts_prev, ts), 
        *
    from i2
)
select speed = delta_m / delta_t * 3.6,
    *
from i3;
```

I think the only "funny business" going on here is the multiplication by 3.6. Because I chose 4326 as the SRID, distances are calculated in meters. And since I'm doing the time calculation in seconds, `delta_m / delta_t` will have units of "meters per second"; 3.6 is the conversion factor to get it into "kilometers per hour".