# Calculating Distance - performance enhancement

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, performance, t-sql

```
declare @Latitude DECIMAL(17, 14)='-29.72216606140100',@Longitude DECIMAL(17, 14)='31.06697845459000'


SELECT DISTINCT 
   *, 
   pm_Latitude, 
   pm_Longitude,
   CASE
       WHEN p.latpoint = pm_Latitude
            AND p.longpoint = pm_Longitude
       THEN CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(8, 2))
       ELSE CAST(p.distance_unit * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)) * COS(RADIANS(pm_Latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(p.longpoint) - RADIANS(pm_Longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(p.latpoint)) * SIN(RADIANS(pm_Latitude)))) AS DECIMAL(8, 2))
   END AS 'pm_Distance'


FROM Pm_PropertyMapping WITH(NOLOCK) CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT @Latitude AS latpoint, 
       @Longitude AS longpoint, 
       100 AS radius, 
       111.045 AS distance_unit
) AS p

WHERE pm_PropertyName LIKE '%' + 'propertyname' + '%'
  AND pm_Latitude BETWEEN p.latpoint - (p.radius / p.distance_unit) AND p.latpoint + (p.radius / p.distance_unit)
  AND pm_Longitude BETWEEN p.longpoint - (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint)))) AND p.longpoint + (p.radius / (p.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(p.latpoint))))

ORDER BY pm_Distance;
```

What this code does is it searches in a table for the closest property given a specific lat and long.

My question is. Is this the most efficient way of calculating distance in SQL?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, you could use the [`geography`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) data type as detailed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude).

Comment: Apparently geography is slower