# How calculate two geo distance (Latitude,Logitude,Altidute) points in Azure Sql server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

How do I get an accurate distance (in meters) given two geo-points (two latitude/longitude/Altitude pair) in Azure Sql server?

Latitude    Longitude   Altitude
22.30634    113.92934   125

Latitude    Longitude   Altitude
58.31962    -157.54788  35000

Is there any possible way to calculate the distance including Altitude in SQL server?

Comment: Google helps ;-) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026675/calculating-distance-between-two-points-latitude-longitude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for the hypotenuse which is `SQRT(Power(L,2)+Power(H,2)`

**To be clear**, this hypotenuse does NOT account for the curvature of the earth.

Here is a little example which shows both.

```
 declare @lat1 float = 22.30634 
 declare @lng1 float = 113.92934
 declare @alt1 float = 125

 declare @lat2 float = 58.31962
 declare @lng2 float = -157.54788
 declare @alt2 float = 35000

 
SELECT JustLatLng = geography::Point(@lat1, @lng1, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@lat2, @lng2, 4326))
      ,WithAlt    = SQRT(Power(geography::Point(@lat1, @lng1, 4326).STDistance(geography::Point(@lat2, @lng2, 4326)),2)
                        +Power((@alt1-@alt2)*0.3048,2))
```

**Returns**

```
JustLatLng          WithAlt
7838823.94282909    7838831.1502063   --<< delta of 7.20737721
```

Comment: Just an after-thought... The ALT should be converted to meters.  Thus the ...*0.3048