# How to calculate distance between multiple points in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, distance, geography

I have table with data from GPS, e.g.: `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `Time`, `UserId`

How to aggregate total distance in specified time frame summing all distances by all points (ordered by time) and group data by user?

Thanks

Comment: For the distance calculation itself you may want to look at <http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist>

Answer (score 6):

If you are using SQL Server, you might be interested in using the geography data type so you can request the database using the dedicated method and geographical index.

The geography data type is available since SQL Server 2008, you can more information right here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Once you've got the data into the geography column, you will be able to calculate the distance between two points using STDistance() methods, see the MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx

Here is an example where STDistance() is used to calculate the distance (with the geographical deformation) between two points returned in meters (international standard unit):

```
DECLARE @pointA geography;
DECLARE @pointB geography;
SET @pointA = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 50)', 4326);
SET @pointB = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @pointA.STDistance(@pointB);
```

If you're using SQL Server 2005 (or if you want to avoid using the geography data type), you can take a look at the MsSQLSpatial project on CodePlex, available here: http://mssqlspatial.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features&referringTitle=Home

Comment: And for some reason, STDistance is case sensitive.

Comment: The actual reason is due to the .Net implementation underlying in the Spatial features (same for Geography or Geometry). In fact, the OGC is defining that it should be ST_Distance in the standard which, I think, has been adapted to the usual SQL Server convention.

Answer (score 5):

The below function gives ***distance between two geocoordinates in miles***

```
create function [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceMiles] (@Lat1 decimal(8,4), @Long1 decimal(8,4), @Lat2 decimal(8,4), @Long2 decimal(8,4))
returns decimal (8,4) as
begin
declare @d decimal(28,10)
-- Convert to radians
set @Lat1 = @Lat1 / 57.2958
set @Long1 = @Long1 / 57.2958
set @Lat2 = @Lat2 / 57.2958
set @Long2 = @Long2 / 57.2958
-- Calc distance
set @d = (Sin(@Lat1) * Sin(@Lat2)) + (Cos(@Lat1) * Cos(@Lat2) * Cos(@Long2 - @Long1))
-- Convert to miles
if @d <> 0
begin
set @d = 3958.75 * Atan(Sqrt(1 - power(@d, 2)) / @d);
end
return @d
end
```

The below function gives ***distance between two geocoordinates in kilometres***

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnCalcDistanceKM(@lat1 FLOAT, @lat2 FLOAT, @lon1 FLOAT, @lon2 FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN ACOS(SIN(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*SIN(PI()*@lat2/180.0)+COS(PI()*@lat1/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lat2/180.0)*COS(PI()*@lon2/180.0-PI()*@lon1/180.0))*6371
END
```

**Usage:**

```
select [dbo].[fnCalcDistanceKM](13.077085,80.262675,13.065701,80.258916)
```

The below function gives ***distance between two geocoordinates in kilometres***
 using ***[Geography](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)*** data type which was introduced in sql server 2008

```
DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = geography::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(-122.360 47.656, -122.343 47.656)', 4326);
SET @h = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-122.34900 47.65100)', 4326);
SELECT @g.STDistance(@h);
```

**Reference:** [Ref1](http://blog.opensourcesql.com/2011/04/calculate-distance-between.html),[Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907943/730807)

I hope this helps

Comment: Note that spheroid computations such as these are accurate to about 10 meters over thousands of km.  If higher accuracy is needed, use Vincenty or Karney's algorithms.

Comment: @N8allan Thanks for pointing out **Vincenty and Karney's algorithms**

Comment: @N8allan I couldn't find any sql scripts for this algorithm. I am going to try to convert the algorithm into SQL scripts when I have free time.